# Looking for multiple ways to solve this problem :)

Tags: probability

Steve wants to buy a chocolate bar and a drink that costs $2.00 each. 
He remembers he has 5 coins in his backpack, but unsure whether they are dimes, quarters or loonies.

What is the probability Steve is able to purchase only one item?

Comment: What are dimes, quarters and loonies??  NB not everyone lives in the same country as you do!

Comment: My mistake! These are Canadian coins and their values are:  dime = $0.10, a quarter= $0.25, a loonie = $1.00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have: $$S=10a+25b+100(5-a-b)=500-90a-75b$$
Where $a$ and $b$ are nonnegative integers such that $a+b\leq5$

And we want:
$$P(200\leq S < 400)$$

List the values of $a$ and $b$ that are possible, the values that work and divide them.

Comment: Thanks so much, I worked through it and your answer helped!